# Google Script to see if text contains a value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a google form that when the user submits it will trigger my function to run which is creating a summary of what they submitted as a Google Doc. I know it can automatically send an email but I need it formatted in a way that my user can edit it later.

There are some check boxes on the form -- but the getResponse() is only populated with the items checked and I need it to show all possible choices. Then I will indicate somehow what was checked.

I can't find a way to see if a text contains a value.
Like in Java with a String, I could do either `.contains("9th")` or `.indexOf("9th") >=0`  and then I would know that the String contains 9th.  How can I do this with google scripts?  Looked all through documentation and I feel like it must be the easiest thing ever.

```
var grade = itemResponse.getResponse();
```

Need to see if grade contains 9th.

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, you can use [markdown](http://Stack Overflow/editing-help) to format code snippets in the body of your post. This helps make your question more concise and readable.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Google Apps Script is javascript, you can use all the string methods...

```
var grade = itemResponse.getResponse();
if(grade.indexOf("9th")>-1){do something }
```

You can find doc on many sites, [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp) for example.

Comment: Thank you! I swear I tried that, along with 20 other things, but now it works!

Comment: glad it helped (I'm sure you did but some detail must have been wrong I guess, things like that happen :-) - please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Note: endsWith() and starsWith() are not Javascript standard until ECMAScript 6 (2015), so Google Apps Script does not support these 2, even though they are in the w3schools.com link you gave, when most browsers support them.
To support these 2 functions, you can add
String.prototype.startsWith = function(prefix) {
    return this.indexOf(prefix) === 0;
}

String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
    return this.match(suffix+"$") == suffix;
}; 
as in http://rickyrosario.com/blog/javascript-startswith-and-endswith-implementation-for-strings/

Answer (score 21):

### Update 2020:

**You can now use Modern ECMAScript syntax thanks to [V8 Runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime)**.

You can use [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
var grade = itemResponse.getResponse();
if(grade.includes("9th")){do something}
```

Comment: how to check if not include ?

Comment: `if(!grade.includes("9th"))` @NoorHossain

Answer (score 7):

I had to add a `.toString` to the item in the values array.  Without it, it would only match if the entire cell body matched the `searchTerm`.

```
function foo() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = ss.getSheetByName('spreadsheet-name');
    var r = s.getRange('A:A');
    var v = r.getValues();
    var searchTerm = 'needle';
    for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
        if(v[0,i].toString().indexOf(searchTerm) > -1) {
            // do something
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the Google Apps Script method `indexOf()` and its results were wrong. So I wrote the small function `Myindexof()`, instead of `indexOf`:

```
function Myindexof(s,text)
{
  var lengths = s.length;
  var lengtht = text.length;
  for (var i = 0;i < lengths - lengtht + 1;i++)
  {
    if (s.substring(i,lengtht + i) == text)
      return i;
  }
  return -1;
}

var s = 'Hello!';
var text = 'llo';
if (Myindexof(s,text) > -1)
   Logger.log('yes');
else
   Logger.log('no');
```

Comment: I don't think you need a routine. .includes will return true or false and result of indexOf can be checked for greater than zero. var src = 'Hello!';
  var text = 'llo';

  var idx = src.indexOf(text);
  Logger.log("indexOf(text) idx: " + idx );  
  //   result: 2
  
  if (src.indexOf(text) > 0 ) 
    Logger.log('Yes');
  else
    Logger.log('No');
  //   result: Yes

  Logger.log("src.includes(text): " + src.includes(text) );
  //   result: true
  
  if (Myindexof(src,text) > -1)
    Logger.log('yes');
  else
    Logger.log('no');
  //   result: yes
}